# Access as the front end and sql server as the backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have some Access tables with many number of fields. I have migrated each access table to 6 or 7 sql server tables. I am using sql server 2008. Now I want to use Access as the front end so that I can enter the data in access but it will be stored in sql server. I know that I have to make a ODBC connection. But I am not sure of how to create a access form to use it as a front-end. I am sorry if it's a basic question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will probably want to start with an empty Access database (since the table structures and any existing forms and reports will not match what you created in SQL server).

First step is to establish an ODBC connection to your SQL Server database.  Then you will "link" the tables in SQL Server to your Access database.

Now, you have an Access database with all the tables that you linked from SQL Server.  Those tables still "live" in SQL Server and when you edit them in Access the data will be stored in SQL Server.

You can then build Access forms and reports using these tables just as if the tables were native to Access.

Comment: Why do you need a DSN or an ODBC connection for an ADP? SQL Server connectivity via SQLOLEDB is built-in. A DSN is a deployment overhead too. ADPs have existed since Access 2000/2003.

Comment: Depends on the user's preferences.  ADP is another valid solution.  My experience is with migrations to linked tables (less important to this user if all the table structures are new).

Comment: @LarryLustig I have done the ODBC connection to the sql server by going to `Administrative Tools->DataSources->System DSN->added the sql server and the database name I wanted to use as front end` Now I have also linked in sql server by using `sp_addlinkedserver 'connect', 'Access 2007','Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'C:\connect.accdb'` but the tables from sql server are not showed up in the empty access database..Where I am going wrong here?

Comment: In Access, find the Linked Table Manager.  Select the tables you want from your SQL Server database.  They should now appear in the table list in Access (with an icon next to them to show that they are linked, not local, tables).

Comment: @LarryLustig Thanks I got it, I was failing in the `linking the tables`. Now I have given the correct path name for the DSN and its working! Will there be any issues to consider in the long term if I continue using access as the front end or should I switch to a dotnet interface (I have to learn and code in dotnet longg process huh!!)

Comment: It's a toss-up.  You can write richer interfaces in more general programming languages, but you can do a lot of development in a short time in Access.

Answer (score 2):

The most versatile way is to use ODBC links to your SQL Server tables and views.  That approach allows you the flexibility to link to other ODBC data sources, tables in other Jet/ACE database files, create Jet/ACE tables locally in your database, link to Excel spreadsheets, and so forth.  You can incorporate a broad range of data sources.

If you choose ADP, you will be limited to OLE DB connection to a single SQL Server instance.  And you will be essentially locked in to SQL Server.  You would not be able to switch the application to a different client-server database without a major re-development effort.

Regarding deployment overhead with ODBC, although you may find it convenient to use a DSN during development, you should convert your ODBC links to DSN-less connections before deployment.  That way your user's won't each require the DSN.  See Doug Steele's page: [Using DSN-Less Connections](http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html)

Comment: I have created an empty access database. I have done the ODBC connection to the sql server by going to `Administrative Tools->DataSources->System DSN->added the sql server and the database` name I wanted to use as front end Now I have also linked in sql server by using `sp_addlinkedserver 'connect', 'Access 2007','Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'C:\connect.accdb'` but the tables from sql server are not showed up in the empty access database..Where I am going wrong here?

Comment: When you create the DSN, don't add anything about Access.  Your DSN will describe the properties for a connection to SQL Server.  It is not an Access-specific thing, but should be usable by any application which can use ODBC connections.

Comment: Thanks I got it, I was failing in the `linking the tables`. Now I have given the correct path name for the DSN and its working! Can you please suggest me which will be the best to use in longterm as a front end Access or an interface in dotnet?

Comment: In your comment to Larry, you indicated a need to learn Dot.Net.  So maybe that's the way you should go.  OTOH, maybe you need a functional form-based interface to SQL Server **now**.  If so, Access is hard to beat for rapid development of database applications.  That's its raison d'être!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create an ODBC connection. You can also create an ADODB connection as well. If your objective is to update or modify a SQL database, both connections will do the trick.

Now, I guess you have to get familiar with the corresponding objects. These should be tables, queries, commands, etc .., that will allow you, for example, to build recordsets out of SQL queries ... Once you are clear with that, you can, for example, assign a recordset to a form through the `Set myForm.recordset = myRecordset.open ...` method.